# Handling encoded characters in ISAPI - Regex

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I have a url that contains a `~`, and I need to handle the encoded version of this character `%7E`.

Currently, we have 2 rules to handle this case.

```
^/folder/([\w-]+)~(\d*).aspx$
^/folder/([\w-]+)%7E(\d*).aspx$
```

Can I combine this into one rule? I tried the following but it does not work:

```
^/folder/([\w-]+)[~|%7E](\d*).aspx$
```

Any help with this rule is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you would like to try

```
^/folder/([\w-]+)(~|%7E)(\d*)\.aspx$
```

or

```
^/folder/([\w-]+)(?:~|%7E)(\d*)\.aspx$
```

to keep your capture groups the same if you regex engine supports this syntax.

This `[…]` constructs a *character class*, not a group of alternatives. So `[~|%7E]` means "either a literal `~`, `|`,  `%`, `7` or `E`.

You have to use parens for that. And you should escape the `.` in `\.aspx` because `.` means "any character" in regexes.

Comment: That works, but changes my existing matches.  So what was $2 is now $3.  Is there a way to keep the matches the same?

Comment: @BrianSalta updated my answer, but you could alternatively just change all occurences from `$2` to `$3`.

Comment: That works, I appreciated the updated answer.  Our rewrite file is quite lengthy, would take a while to update all the new capture groups.